# Chrome WebRequest Redirect to Blob URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension and using chrome.webRequest to intercept all GET requests. One of the request gets an XML file from http://test.com/bla.xml. I have this file saved as a blob in chrome local storage.

```
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobData); // blobUrl created earlier in code

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        if (details.url === 'http://test.com/bla.xml') {

            console.log($.get(blobUrl)) // this works 

            return { redirectUrl: blobUrl }; // this fails. 
        }
```

The problem occurs when I try to return with the updated redirectUrl. I can see in chrome > inspect > network that the first jquery GET request processes fine, and retrieves the file via the blobUrl. However, the original redirected request will give me a 404 not found. If I follow the link in the 404, it is the same link as the one used in jquery, and it is found when I go to it in my browser.

Comment: Please show the full call of `addListener`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?